# .htaccess pretty url with and without parameter and slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have below code in my .htaccess file. When I open https://example.com/tran it shows 404 page but adding slash in url like https://example.com/tran/ works.
How can I make https://example.com/tran to redirect to https://example.com/tran/ and https://example.com/tran/parameter1 both work because also want to get parameter from url using $_GET method when it is available in url.

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteRule tran/(.*) transaction.php?id=$1

RewriteRule tran/(.*)/ transaction.php?id=$1

RewriteRule addr/(.*) address.php?id=$1   

RewriteRule addr/(.*)/ address.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule tran(?:/(.*?)/?)?$ transaction.php?id=$1
RewriteRule addr(?:/(.*?)/?)?$ address.php?id=$1
```

instead of your 4 rules